# Why does a caught System.UnauthorizedAccessException exception redirect me to an error page?

Tags: permissions

When this code executes in a custom web part:

```
try{
   ...Offending code here...
}
catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException e)
{
     //Do nothing if the user doesn't have access to the site or list.
}
```

I am redirected to the _layouts/AccessDenied.aspx error page that displays: "Error: Access Denied".  Shouldn't the handled exception be ignored?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user doesn't have access to the page your web part is running on then it will never reach that code.

You might be able to override PreInit or one of the other page lifecycle events, but even then I don't see how your specific code is going to override the fact that they don't have access.

Here's a page lifecycle reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

You can also try something like this, but again you have to be able to set it as early on in the page lifecycle for it to have any chance of working:

http://sridharu.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-avoid-access-denied-page.html

Comment: The web part is actually on a site that the user does have access to.  However, the code aggregates list content from multiple subsites, some of which the user does not have access to.   When iterating through the SPWeb objects, the error is raised when the list is queried.  I just want to wrap that it a try/catch block but it seems to redirect me regardless.

Comment: OK, in that case use the approach in the 2nd link I posted...setting SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException before executing your code and returning it to original value after you're done.

Comment: I found a workaround - we keep track of which sites users should have access to in a database. I'm now only iterating through sites the user should have access to and avoiding the error. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because SharePoint's error handling treats the `UnauthorizedAccessException` as a special exception and will ALWAYS redirect to the access denied page, there's even a special method to handle it:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException
```

You can turn this of by settings the following property:

```
SPSite.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
```

P.S. it is not necessary to use an external database to get a list of all SPSite's a user has access to, this can be done using Search:[Sites i have access to by Wonderlaura](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=98).

She mentions it is enterprise only, but since you are doing this in code, it'll work for any version but Foundation / WSS3 by using the `FullTextSqlQuery` class and then query for `contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web contentClass:sts_listitem_850`